# Override configuration prefix on IBM MQ Starter - change prefix from ibm.mq to infrastructure.ibm.mq

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

MQ starter has

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ibm.mq")
public class MQConfigurationProperties {
```

I want to change the config prefix to `infrastructure.ibm.mq` and the rest of the hiearchy on the
config is the same

I want to avoid changing the `MQConfiguration.java` file, and recompiling, I just want to use the starter as is, but use a slightly different config prefix

Answer (score 0):

This is one way I was able to override it. The `@Primary` means that this takes precedence. Otherwise you get errors about finding 2 beans where only a single is accepted.

```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.local.prefix")
  public MQConfigurationProperties localConfigurationProperties() {
    return new MQConfigurationProperties();
  }
```